# Why does the dipole moment order of group 15 hydrides increase down the group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, dipole

The order given in my book is

> $$\ce{NH3} > \ce{SbH3} > \ce{AsH3} > \ce{PH3}$$

Phosphorous is more electronegative than arsenic and antimony. Then shouldn't the dipole moment be more in case of $\ce{PH3}?$

And why does the anomaly of $\ce{NH3}$ occur?

Comment: Geometry/symmetry  also has a role in determining the dipole, for example, if the molecules were planar  as is $\ce{BF3}$  the dipole would be zero.

Comment: @porphyrin could you convert this into a proper answer for this question

Answer (score 4):

The query you have is a common mistake, and this is aksed as a very common question in examinations, well, I wouldn't blame you as the reason is simple but not easy to think of.

What you said about *E.N.* of phosphorous being more than arsenic and antimony is absolutely correct. But what you missed, is that lower down the group the direction of dipole itself **reverses**.

*E.N.* of $\ce{P}$ is $2.19$, while that of $\ce{As}$ is $2.18$ and of $\ce{Sb}$ is $2.05$

Whereas H as an *E.N.* of $2.20$. So hence now you can see clearly that your order is justified, as in actuality, H becomes the negative end of the dipole.

Another factor that further widens this gap is that the dipole vector in chemistry notations is from + to-, which means all vectors add up in case of $\ce{As}$ and Sb

Comment: Why should I not use doubt? @The_Vinz ?